# Code does not wait for user to finish typing in the repeat password section

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to setup a signup view with using parse.com as backend but for some reason whenever i start typing in the reenter password field, as soon as i type something, it starts going through this

```
else if ([password compare:passwordAgain] != NSOrderedSame) {
        // We have non-zero strings.
        // Check for equal password strings.
            textError = YES;
            errorText = [errorText stringByAppendingString:passwordMismatchText];
            [_reEnterPasswordField becomeFirstResponder];
            NSLog(@"stops here");


    }
```

method and sends me the error message passwordMismatchText. It goes through this message everytime i change a word whether i added or deleted it. When I use the same methods with xib the files i had no problem. But after I try to do the same thing with storyboards I am having this issue. I tried creating a user default for _doneButton.enabled == YES and put an another if around the errorText =[...] message, but did not solve the problem. I appreciate for the help.

SignUpViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SignUpViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userNameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *reEnterPasswordField;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;

@end
```

SignUpViewController.m

```
#import "SignUpViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "ActivityView.h"
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

@interface SignUpViewController ()
- (void)textInputChanged:(NSNotification *)note;
-(void)processFieldEntries;
- (BOOL)shouldEnableDoneButton;
@end
```

@implementation SignUpViewController

```
@synthesize doneButton = _doneButton;
@synthesize userNameField = _userNameField;
@synthesize passwordField = _passwordField;
@synthesize reEnterPasswordField = _reEnterPasswordField;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textInputChanged:) name:  UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:_userNameField];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textInputChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:_passwordField];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textInputChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:_reEnterPasswordField];

    _doneButton.enabled = NO;
    NSLog(@"nsnotification is working fine");

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_userNameField becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"indeed usernamefield became a first responder");

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == _userNameField ) {
        [_userNameField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField == _passwordField) {
        [_passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField == _reEnterPasswordField)
    {
        [_reEnterPasswordField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    NSLog(@"keyboard action works fine ");
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)shouldEnableDoneButton
{
    BOOL enableDoneButton = NO;

    if (_userNameField.text != nil &&
        _userNameField.text.length > 0 &&
        _passwordField.text != nil &&
        _passwordField.text.length > 0 &&
        _reEnterPasswordField.text != nil &&
        _reEnterPasswordField.text.length > 0)
    {
        [self processFieldEntries];
        enableDoneButton = YES;
        NSLog(@"done button enabled");
    }
    return enableDoneButton;

}
-(void)textInputChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    _doneButton.enabled = [self shouldEnableDoneButton];

}
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [_userNameField resignFirstResponder];
    [_passwordField resignFirstResponder];
    [_reEnterPasswordField resignFirstResponder];
    [self processFieldEntries];
    NSLog(@"do you see this");
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(void)processFieldEntries
{
    // Check that we have a non-zero username and passwords.
    // Compare password and passwordAgain for equality
    // Throw up a dialog that tells them what they did wrong if they did it wrong.

    NSString *username = _userNameField.text;
    NSString *password = _passwordField.text;
    NSString *passwordAgain = _reEnterPasswordField.text;
    NSString *errorText = @"Please ";
    NSString *usernameBlankText = @"enter a username";
    NSString *passwordBlankText = @"enter a password";
    NSString *joinText = @", and ";
    NSString *passwordMismatchText = @"enter the same password twice";
    BOOL textError = NO;
    NSLog(@"validation begins here");

    // Messaging nil will return 0, so these checks implicitly check for nil text.
    if (username.length == 0 || password.length == 0 || passwordAgain.length == 0) {
        textError = YES;

        // Set up the keyboard for the first field missing input:
        if (passwordAgain.length == 0) {
            [_reEnterPasswordField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        if (password.length == 0) {
            [_passwordField becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        if (username.length == 0) {
            [_userNameField becomeFirstResponder];
        }

        if (username.length == 0) {
            errorText = [errorText stringByAppendingString:usernameBlankText];
        }

        if (password.length == 0 || passwordAgain.length == 0) {
            if (username.length == 0) { // We need some joining text in the error:
                errorText = [errorText stringByAppendingString:joinText];
            }
            errorText = [errorText stringByAppendingString:passwordBlankText];
        }
    } else if ([password compare:passwordAgain] != NSOrderedSame) {
        // We have non-zero strings.
        // Check for equal password strings.
            textError = YES;
            errorText = [errorText stringByAppendingString:passwordMismatchText];
            [_reEnterPasswordField becomeFirstResponder];
            NSLog(@"stops here");


    }
    if (textError) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:errorText message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alertView show];
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"validation works just fine");

    // Everything looks good; try to log in.
    // Disable the done button for now.
    _doneButton.enabled = NO;
    ActivityView *activityCircle = [[ActivityView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    UILabel *label = activityCircle.label;
    label.text = @"Signing You Up";
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.f];
    [activityCircle.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [activityCircle layoutSubviews];

    [self.view addSubview:activityCircle];
    NSLog(@"activity view works just fine");

    //parse registeration
    // Call into an object somewhere that has code for setting up a user.
    // The app delegate cares about this, but so do a lot of other objects.
    // For now, do this inline.

    PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
    user.username = username;
    user.password = password;
    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"] message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
            [alertView show];
            _doneButton.enabled = [self shouldEnableDoneButton];
            [activityCircle.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [activityCircle removeFromSuperview];
            // Bring the keyboard back up, because they'll probably need to change something.
            [_userNameField becomeFirstResponder];
            return;
        }
        // Success!
        [activityCircle.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [activityCircle removeFromSuperview];
        //add the next screen here
    }];
    NSLog(@"user signedup just fine");
    //now pass the view from sign up to profile view
}
/*
 //this one didnt work
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    ProfileViewController *myProfileView = [segue destinationViewController];
    if (_doneButton.enabled == YES) {
           [myProfileView performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignUpSegue" sender:_doneButton];
    }


}
 */
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"is this method visible");
    if (_doneButton.enabled == YES) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SignUpSegue" sender:_doneButton];
    }

return NO;

}

 @end
```

this is the log files that I am getting

```
2013-09-06 02:49:19.938  nsnotification is working fine
2013-09-06 02:49:19.942  indeed usernamefield became a first responder
2013-09-06 02:49:47.446  validation begins here
2013-09-06 02:49:47.448  stops here
2013-09-06 02:49:47.485  done button enabled
2013-09-06 02:49:49.271  validation begins here
2013-09-06 02:49:49.273  stops here
2013-09-06 02:49:49.296  done button enabled
2013-09-06 02:49:51.257  validation begins here
2013-09-06 02:49:51.259  validation works just fine
2013-09-06 02:49:51.265  activity view works just fine
2013-09-06 02:49:51.270  user signedup just fine
2013-09-06 02:49:51.271  done button enabled
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the compiler, or Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering the code to run by your observation of `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`. As this moves through your methods you eventually call `processFieldEntries`. Probably you shouldn't be calling `processFieldEntries` from `shouldEnableDoneButton`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Originally I was calling from the done action - (IBAction)done:(id)sender but when do that it skips the processFieldEntries method, thus it does not validate at all. This is the log 2013-09-06 03:21:42.025 [68194:c07] nsnotification is working fine
2013-09-06 03:21:42.026  indeed usernamefield became a first responder
2013-09-06 03:21:45.215  done button enabled
2013-09-06 03:21:45.471  done button enabled
2013-09-06 03:21:47.381  is this method visible. Any idea why?

Comment: How does it 'skip' the method? How are you verifying this?

Comment: when i say 'skip', i meant as it does not read the NSLog(@"validation begins here"); which is in the processFieldEntries method. And it seems like when i put an another nslog to inside the done action, which is connect to done bar button item, it doesn't see the that one either. So thank you for taking time to go over.

Comment: So the `done:` method isn't being called. How is it connection / what is it connected to?

Comment: http://puu.sh/4knAA.jpg this is how the storyboard is.I deleted the done (action) and recreated as doneAction also.

Comment: http://puu.sh/4knRc. I created an exception point to for on catch. It seems like I am not doing the segue right.

Comment: Trigger the segue from code. If the validation passed, then trigger.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36937/discussion-between-mett-and-wain)